# Authorization with Facebook OAuth. How does Logging into Facebook Authorize my App?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I need to implement user authorization using Facebook OAuth for my page exactly as it is done here at Stack Overflow. I know how to obtain an access token from Facebook but don't know what to do with it next. Could your please provide me with a link to some guide?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Stack overflow uses open ID along with Oauth.  You can read about it here:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246

Comment: Facebook is not an OpenId provider it just allows its users to login with Google's OpenId. So it seems that Stack Overflow somehow uses OAuth protocol.

Answer (score 0):

[Temboo](http://www.temboo.com) makes it simple to implement Facebook OAuth by breaking the process down into two steps:

- `ÌnitializeOAuth` returns the Facebook authorization URL that you need to show your users so that they can grant your app access to their Facebook accounts.
- `FinalizeOAuth` returns the access token you need to programmatically read/write a user's Facebook data.

What's more, you can test these calls from your browser and then generate the source code you need in the language of your choice.

Here's a [short video](https://www.temboo.com/videos#oauthchoreos) that shows you how to do this with Temboo.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)